# Templates in JavaServer Faces 2.0

Tags: java, templates, jsf-2

I'm trying for the first time to use templates with JSF 2.0 with Eclipse, but I'm having problems.

The original `index.xhtml` page works correctly, and when I click on a button, everything works fine.  However, if I change the index page so that it uses a template file it no longer works properly.  The modified `index.xhtml` page is here:

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
  template="/templates/main-template.xhtml">
  <ui:define name="title">
    Simulator using JSF 2.0 - Test Version 2
  </ui:define> 
  <ui:define name="header">      
    Home Page of the Simulator using JSF 2.0 - Test Version 2
  </ui:define>
  <ui:define name="body">
    Click on the button to select the required option
    <h:outputText value="and login" rendered="#{!login.loggedIn}"/>
    <h:form prependId="false">   
      <h:commandButton value="Option 1" action="#{login.option1}"/>
      <h:commandButton value="Option 2" action="#{login.option2}"/>
      <h:commandButton value="Option 3" action="#{login.option3}"/>
      <h:commandButton value="Logout" disabled="#{!login.loggedIn}" action="#{login.logout}"/>
    </h:form>   
  </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

and the template file, `main.template.xhtml`, is in the sub-folder templates, is here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"  
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
  <h:head>
    <title>
      <ui:insert name="title">Title</ui:insert>
    </title>
  </h:head>      
  <h:body>
    <ui:insert name="header">Header</ui:insert>
    <br/>
    We are in template.xhtml
    <br/>
    <ui:insert name="body">Body</ui:insert>
  </h:body>
</html>
```

If I remove all code with the "h" tags in index.xhtml, the file picks up correctly the code in templates/main-template.xhtml, so the path is correct.  However, if I include code with the "h" tags, as is here, Eclipse complains that the tags are not recognized and the page fails.

If I include the line `xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"` at the top, then Eclipse recognized the "h" tags and the page is correctly rendered, but the application fails when I click a button, and returns the error:

> javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException:
>   /index.xhtml @15,68 action="#{login.option1}": Target Unreachable,
>   identifier 'login' resolved to null

Perhaps somehow the line `xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"` in the template file is messing things up, but the whole idea of templates is to include as much common code in a template file.

Does anybody have any idea what is going on, and what the solution to this is?

The `web.xml` and `faces-config.xml` are standard, and don't think anything has to be done with them.

Comment: StackOverflow is not just a forum, it is also a wiki and a blog. See http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/09/stack-overflow-none-of-us-is-as-dumb-as-all-of-us.html

Answer (score 1):

Your idea of how templates should work seems correct, but there are some points that we should clarify. Maybe this would help you:

**Namespaces**

About namespaces, whenever you use a tag library in a page, you should declare it's namespace. Even if you're using templates and you've declared them in your template. You could think that namespace declarations are not inherited, if it helps.

In this case I see that you `index.xhtml` page is using `h:commandButton` but hasn't declared its namespace.

**Beans**

For a bean to be found by `EL` you should have the following:

A class annotated with `@ManagedBean` importing from `javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean` package, like this:

```
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;

@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class Login 
{
    // ...
}
```

In this case your bean should be found by `EL` by the name `login`, by convention. (Decapitalize the first letter of your class name)

Or you could give it a name:

```
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;

@ManagedBean(name="login")
@ViewScoped
public class MyLoginBean
{
    // ...
}
```

In this case, by convention it would be called `myLoginBean` but we gave it a name, in this case `login`, so `EL` should find it by the name `login`.

If you want to use CDI instead of plain JSF, you could use `@Named` annotation to define how your bean should be found by `EL`, following the same naming convention.

```
import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;

@Named(value="login")
@RequestScoped
public class MyLoginBean
{
    // ...
}
```

Remember that data that you want `EL` to find and change must have the proper getters and setters.

**Hint**

I would kindly suggest that you create simpler code in order to test funcionality. In this case you could test templating first and then bean, actions, etc...

I hope it helps.

Comment: import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;

Comment: Many thanks, but I think I have my bean set up correctly (other than the naming convention) as follows:

Comment: @ManagedBean(name="login")
@SessionScoped
public class LoginBean implements Serializable {

// Getters, setters and private methods

}

Comment: Sorry, a this is my first attempt here, I've messed up with how comments are added.  Anyway, I wanted to say that I had set up my bean with the 2nd of your code samples, except that I had named it LoginBean and used @SessionScoped.  I have all the getters and setters, and it worked correctly before I changed index.xhtml to use a template file.